# Dynamic with RegionNearest keeps one CPU core at 100% - Is this a bug?

Tags: dynamic

Normally, when you use `Dynamic` with a CPU-intensive expression, the expression only gets evaluated when a symbol in the expression changes. This doesn't seem to work with `RegionNearest`:

```
d = RegionIntersection[Ellipsoid[{2., 2.}, {5, 3}], 
   Ellipsoid[{5., 3.}, {4, 3}]];    
nf = RegionNearest[d];
pt = {0, 0};
```

`Timing[nf[pt]]` tells me that this takes .6s on my PC (side question: why does this take so long? I thought this would be equivalent to finding the nearest point to each of the two ellipsoids, then checking if that point is contained in the other.)

Now when I write:

```
Dynamic[nf[pt]]
```

The Mathematica kernel goes to 25% CPU utilization (one core) and stays there, even when nothing changes.

Is this a bug?

**ADD:** as @Nasser remarked in a comment, `Dynamic[nf[pt]]` doesn't make much sense on it's own. My actual code was:

```
LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt],
 Show[
  Graphics[Dynamic[Line[{pt, nf[pt]}]]],
  RegionPlot[d]]]
```

But `Dynamic[nf[pt]]` is the simplest way to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I do not know why the cpu goes full speed, strange things happen when Dynamic are not used correctly. Your use of Dynamic is not right really. I am not sure what you are trying to do with `Dynamic[nf[pt]]`. One should use Dynamic around objects that gets displayed by front end, so that the FE updates them automatically without the kernel having to do anything, and not around the computation itself that goes to the kernel. May be you wanted to do `Dynamic[r]` then `r=nf[pt]` ?

Comment: @Nasser: My original code had a `LocatorPane` to move `pt` around, containing a `Graphics` that showed a line from `pt` to the nearest point, and a `RegionPlot` of the intersection. I've simplified it to find the root problem, and only posted that. You can imagine a `Locator` moving `pt` around somewhere else in the notebook, but it doesn't really change anything.

Comment: Related: [link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/52279/antialiased-text-in-manipulate-constantly-re-evaluated-ignores-trackedsymbols/52283#52283)

Comment: @Nasser: It crashed my kernel a few times, too. But every time I restarted the kernel and executed the same code, it worked. So I have no code to reproduce that problem.

Comment: me too. It crashed it few times. I thought may be it was just random dynamic thing. Was not sure.... something strange seems to be going on with this RegionIntersection function, I never used it before....

Comment: This looks like a bug worth reporting. In the meantime you can work around it using `Refresh`

Comment: I reported this as a bug to WRI. I also found a reproducible way to crash the kernel using `Dynamic`, reported that too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it's a bug worth reporting. In the meantime you can work around it using `Refresh`. Perhaps something like the following

```
Unprotect[RegionNearestFunction];
Module[{inside},
 rnf : _RegionNearestFunction[___] /; ! TrueQ[inside] := 
  Block[{inside = True}, Refresh[rnf, None]]
 ]
Protect[RegionNearestFunction];
```